# Is there a LaTeX package for this beautiful "typewriter" font?

Tags: fonts

[image]

I love this beautiful typewriter font.  Is there a LaTeX package for this?

Comment: You didn't  say which font it is. You cant take a look at the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: I assume that it is not a digital font at all but a scan of a document set with a typewriter, you could use the typewriter package

Comment: Yes I don't think it's a digital font.  I'm not sure which typewriter font it is.

Comment: typewriters don't really have a font as understood by a typesetting system, they just have a ribbon and some hammers.

Comment: If nothing in the LaTeX font catalogue suits you, there are literally hundreds of typewriter fonts identified on the web.  Search "typewriter fonts" to identify some good match to what you want.  Then worry about getting that in LaTeX.